# how to overwrite springboot configuration properties through command line

Tags: spring-boot, command-line, properties

Suppose I have springboot application and I want to overwrite one of its property from application.properties file ,for example  spring.datasource.username=root to  spring.datasource.username=user . How can i do it through commandline ? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to overwrite it without restarting the app, you need to know that you can't do that without "Spring Cloud Config"; otherwise I don't see any point to overwrite it through anywhere !!

With "Spring Cloud Config" and some other tools such as "Vault", you can change any property at any time without restarting your app.

But if you mean you want to overwrite these property because of some security policy, you can use environment variables and read the values from them (The "HOW" is depend on your environment).

Comment: first of all thank you for the info..... i have 2 questions after reading your comment... first even if restarting is fine ,,, then how ? ..... and second... using spring cloud config.. how i change  the properties through command line?

Comment: If it's ok to restart your app, just change application.properties file, then restart you app!!! If you can't edit it (for any reason), use environment variables like this: set "spring.datasource.username=${USERNAME}" on application.properties file and set "USERNAME=user" on your machine and change it anytime you want and restart your app.

Comment: about spring cloud config, I just suggest it; to run it, you need to do a lot of work !!

Comment: well,,,l wanted to know if i can  use command line for this need..... suppose I have a jar in a server and i need to change its property file via commad line and execute it.

Comment: So use "vi", "vim" or "nano" to edit your file in command line or use the combination of "cat, echo, grep, awk, sed, cut" commands.

Comment: I'm talking about application.properties files. create this file, write your properties in it, and pass this file to your jar file at runtime. Now you can edit it anytime you want and apply your changes by restarting your app !!!